# How to cout with input in c++?

Tags: c++

Hello guys actually i want to show output with input

e.g:

```
int main()

   int a, b, c;

    cin >>a >>b;
c = a-b;

cout <<"Here would be input e.g: 4+5=" << c <<endl;
cout <<"Here would be input e.g: 4-5=" << e <<endl;
```

If input is in this format a+b and user enter input's then output show after input like this 4+5= and after equal answer would there. Thanx in advance

Comment: What exactly is the problem?

Comment: You need to define `e`, as in `e = a + b;`.

Comment: (I prefer to be presented *commented*/documented code. Code that stands a chance passing a compiler, at that.) What *is* your [answerable programming question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    cout << "Here would be input e.g: " << a << "+" << b<<"=" << c << endl;
    cout << "Here would be input e.g: " << a << "-" << b<<"=" << e << endl;
```

Comment: Thank you so much it worked.

Answer (score -1):

Add the input variables in the cout command as follows:

> cout << a << " + " << b<<" = " << c << endl;

Comment: Well, Spinkoo already suggested the same thing.